# Unable to boot into Ubuntu 12.10 installed outside windows 8

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, secure-boot

I am using Sony vaio E series. I installed Ubuntu in one drive. But when I restarted the system it directly goes into windows without showing any options for ubuntu 12.10.I am new to Ubuntu. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you install in UEFI boot mode or BIOS boot mode? And even if UEFI mode you need to go into UEFI and choose the ubuntu entry.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Ubuntu doesn't support Secure Boot. (it is not signed) All Computers that came along with Windows 8 have Secure Boot enabled.

Check your BIOS Setup and search for `Secure Boot`. Set it to `[Disabled]`. If you can't find it, search for a BIOS/EFI update on the internet.

As soon as you've disabled Secure Boot, you should be able to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu does support secure boot. If you boot installer in secure boot mode with UEFI it will install in secure boot mode. But generally better not to use secure boot.

Comment: Really? Thanks, now I know too. (My PC doesn't have EFI at all...)